# How to implement the constractures and istrem\ostrem and operaturs in polynomial class using linked list includind monomial class C++

Tags: c++, oop

I need to create two classes one for Monomials. The other for polynomials (built using a linked list of Monomials).
i created the class Monomials and it's working , but i'm stuck with the implementions of class polynomials 
Operator: =
+, - (between polynomials and between polynomials and polynomials)
= +, = - (with right or right polynomial)
- Unry
==, =!
I / O operators
() Revaluation operator. That is, p (r) returns the polynomial value p for x = r
[] Coefficient retrieval and positioning operators.
I need guidance with one operator and how build the istrem \ ostrem \ constructors, from there I will continue alone
this is the main :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "Monomial.h"
#include "Polynomial.h"
using namespace std;

void testMonomial() {
Monomial m1, m2;

do {
    cout << "Enter two monomials m1 and m2: " << endl;
    cin >> m1 >> m2;
    cout << "m1= " << m1 << ",m2= " << m2 << endl;
    cout << "m1+m2= " << m1 + m2 << endl;
    cout << "m1-m2= " << m1 - m2 << endl;
    cout << "m1*m2= " << m1 * m2 << endl;
        m1 *= 2; //m1=m1*2
    cout << "m1 *= 2, m1= " << m1 << endl;
        m2 += m1;  // m2 = m2 + m1
    cout << "m2 += m1, m1= " << m1 << ",m2=" << m2 << endl;
  } 
  while (m1 != 0 || m2 != 0);
}

void testPolynomial() {
Polynomial p;

cout << "p=" << p << endl;
cout << "Adding one to p" << endl;
p += Monomial(1);
cout << "p=" << p << endl;

cout << "Adding x^2 to p" << endl;
p += Monomial(1, 2);
cout << "p=" << p << endl;

cout << "Adding -x^2 to p" << endl;
p += Monomial(-1, 2);
cout << "p=" << p << endl;

cout << "Number of Monomials=" << Monomial::getNumberOfMonomials() << endl;
do {
    cout << "Enter a polynomial: " << endl;
    cin >> p;
    cout << p << endl;
    cout << "p(0)=" << p(0) << ", p(1)=" << p(1) << ", p(2)=" << p(2) << endl;
    cout << "p[0]=" << p[0] << ", p[1]=" << p[1] << ", p[2]=" << p[2] << ", p[4]=" << p[4] << endl;
    cout << "p+p=" << p + p << endl;
} while (p != Monomial(0));
  }

 //Enter a polynomial :
 1
 p(0) = 1, p(1) = 1, p(2) = 1
 p[0] = 1, p[1] = 0, p[2] = 0, p[4] = 0
 p + p = 2
 int main() {
cout << boolalpha;
testMonomial();
cout << "Number of Monomials=" << Monomial::getNumberOfMonomials() << endl;
testPolynomial();
cout << "Number of Monomials=" << Monomial::getNumberOfMonomials() << endl;
return 0;
}
enter code here
```

this is the monomial.h 
      class Monomial {

```
friend ostream & operator<< (ostream & out, const Monomial & mono);
friend istream & operator>>(istream &, Monomial &);


public:
Monomial(void);
Monomial(int coefficient, int degree);
Monomial(const Monomial &other);
Monomial(int a);  
~Monomial();
void setCoff(int);
void setExpo(int);
bool operator != (const Monomial &other);
bool operator != (int other);
const Monomial& operator = (const Monomial&);
Monomial operator + (const Monomial&) const;
Monomial operator - (const Monomial&) const;
Monomial operator * (const Monomial&);
const Monomial operator*=(const Monomial&);
const Monomial operator*=(int num);
const Monomial operator += (const Monomial&);
const Monomial operator+=(int num);
// Monomial operator- (const Monomial& right) const;
int getCoefficient() const;
int getDegree() const;
void print() const;
static int getNumberOfMonomials();
private:
int coefficient;
int degree;
static int numberOfMonomials;
};
```

this class Monomial.cpp
    using namespace std;

```
int Monomial::numberOfMonomials = 0;

 Monomial::Monomial(void)
{
 numberOfMonomials++;
 }
 Monomial::Monomial(int a)
 {
 setCoff(a);
 setExpo(0);
 numberOfMonomials++;
}
Monomial::Monomial(int a, int b)
{
 setCoff(a);
 setExpo(b);
 numberOfMonomials++;
}


 Monomial::Monomial(const Monomial& other) : degree(other.degree)
 {
 this->coefficient = other.coefficient;
 numberOfMonomials++;
}

 Monomial::~Monomial()
 {
  numberOfMonomials--;
  }
int Monomial::getCoefficient() const
 {
 return coefficient;
 }

 int Monomial::getDegree() const
  {
 return degree;
  }
 void Monomial::setCoff(int x)
  {
coefficient = x;
 }

 void Monomial::setExpo(int x)
 {
 degree = x;
  }


 const Monomial& Monomial:: operator = (const Monomial& right)
{
coefficient = right.coefficient;
degree = right.degree;
return (*this);
 }

 Monomial Monomial:: operator + (const Monomial& right) const
 {
Monomial res;
if (right.degree == degree)
{
    if (right.degree != 0)
    {
        res.setCoff(this->getCoefficient() + right.getCoefficient());
        res.setExpo(this->getDegree() + res.getDegree());
        return (res);
    }
    res.setCoff(this->getCoefficient() + right.getCoefficient());
    res.setExpo(0);
    return (res);

  }
 res.setCoff(this->getCoefficient());
 res.setExpo(this->getDegree());
 return (res);
}

 Monomial Monomial:: operator - (const Monomial& right) const
  {
   Monomial res;
   if (right.degree == degree)
 {
    res.setCoff(this->getCoefficient() - right.getCoefficient());
    res.setExpo(this->getDegree());
    return (res);
   }
    res.setCoff(this->getCoefficient());
    res.setExpo(this->getDegree());
   return (res);
   }

    Monomial Monomial:: operator * (const Monomial& right)
  {
  Monomial res;

   res.setCoff(coefficient * right.getCoefficient());
  res.setExpo(degree + right.getDegree());

  return (res);
  }



  const Monomial Monomial:: operator*=(const Monomial& right)
  {
   Monomial res;
   if (right.getCoefficient() == 0)
   {

    this->coefficient *= 0;
    this->degree *= 0;
    return (*this);
    /*  res.coefficient *= 0;
        res.degree *= 0;
        return Monomial(coefficient, degree);*/

    }
   this->coefficient *= right.getCoefficient();
  this->degree += right.getDegree();
  return (*this);
  }
const Monomial Monomial:: operator*=(int num)
  {
this->coefficient *= num;
this->degree /*+= this->getDegree()*/;
return (*this);

 }




   const Monomial Monomial:: operator += (const Monomial& right)
  {
    if (right.degree == degree)
   {
    return Monomial(this->coefficient += right.coefficient, degree);
   }
  return (*this);
  }
 const Monomial Monomial:: operator+=(int num)
  {
this->coefficient += num;
this->degree += this->getDegree();
return (*this);

 }

   bool Monomial:: operator != (const Monomial& other)
    {
   if (this->getCoefficient() == other.getCoefficient() && this->getDegree() == other.getDegree())
   {
    return true;
   }
   return false;
  }


  bool Monomial:: operator != (int other)
   {
    if (this->getDegree() == 0)
  {
    if (this->getCoefficient() == other)
    {
        return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
  }


   void Monomial::print() const {
    if (coefficient != 1 || degree == 0) cout << coefficient;
    if (coefficient != 1 && degree > 0) cout << "*";
    if (degree > 0) cout << "x";
    if (degree > 1) cout << "^" << degree;
    }

   int Monomial::getNumberOfMonomials() {
  return numberOfMonomials;
    }

  ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const Monomial &r)
  {
  if (r.coefficient == 0 || r.coefficient != 0)
  {

    if (r.coefficient == 1 && r.degree == 1)
        out << "x";
    else if (r.coefficient == 0 && r.degree == 0)
        out << "0";
    else if (r.coefficient == (-1) && r.degree == 1)
        out << r.coefficient << " * x";
    else if (r.degree == 1)
        out << r.coefficient << " * x";
    else if (r.degree == 0 && r.coefficient != 0)
        out << r.coefficient;
    else if (r.coefficient == 1 && r.degree)
        out << "  x ^ " << r.degree;
    else
        out << r.coefficient << " * x ^ " << r.degree;
    }
   return out;
  }
   istream &operator>>(istream &in, Monomial &r)
   {
   in >> r.coefficient;
   in >> r.degree;
   return in;
   }
```

Comment: This site isn't a code writing service. Please explain what's going wrong with your current code and formulate a simple question that we can answer. Also, it's worth expending a little effort on the spelling. I realise you're not a native English speaker, but it's not too hard to fix errors like 'constracture' for 'constructor' and 'includind' for 'including'.

Comment: i wrote i need help how implement the istrem\ostrem , and one operator in class polinom , and i will continue alone

Comment: `3x^2 + 4` = `7x^4`? Seems odd to me.